# Conformal maps and flow around corners

Tags: fluid-dynamics

The complex potential $\Psi = \psi + i \phi$ ($\psi$ is the velocity potential, $\phi$ the stream function) is an analytical function for an irrotational inviscid flow, since its constituents in this case satisfy Laplace's equation.

However, say I look at flow around a corner with some angle $\alpha$. How does the conformal map enter into all of this? Why is it useful?

Comment: Do you know any complex analysis? If yes, the complex potential satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann conditions i.e., it is holomorphic in the complex coordinate. You can then use conformal mapping to convert a wedge into the plane with a branch cut running from 0 to $\infty$.

Comment: @suresh I know complex analysis and that the complex potential is harmonic. But what I don't quite understand is why it works -- why are we allowed to transform our domain?

Comment: I guess it is easier to solve the problem on the plane and then convert it to the solution for a wedge. Conformal maps don't mess up holomorphy.

Comment: @suresh The map $w^{3/2}$ takes us from the upper plane to a "wedge"-plane (I believe). With this at hand, how do I solve the wedge-problem?

Comment: You can try to make sense of all the examples given here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potential_flow